# How to get only 1 tag using new DOMDocument

Tags: php

I only want to get the first iframe. how should I do that?

here is my code:

```
 $url = "http://www.flixxy.com/10-famous-movie-scenes.htm";
 $page = new DOMDocument;
 $page->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
 foreach ($page->getElementsByTagName('iframe') as $node) {
    echo $node->getAttribute('src');
 }
```

i'm just new in this. thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getElementsByTagName()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagname.php)  returns a `DOMNodeList` of all the matched tags. Since you only want the first tag, the `foreach` loop is not required. You can simply use the [`item()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php) method to traverse the `DOMNodeList` and retrieve the first iframe tag:

```
$nodes = $page->getElementsByTagName('iframe');    // get all the tags
echo $node->item(0)->getAttribute('src');          // get the attribute
```

You can shorten and make it one-line, if you want:

```
echo $page->getElementsByTagName('iframe')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

Comment: just a minor nitpicking, `$node` should be called `$nodes` because it usually behaves like an array of multiple elements, and that's why you later do `->item(0)`, to get the first iframe :)

Comment: @Shikiryu: Yeah, I agree. I've updated the answer to reflect this :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Where is the tutorial for this?

Comment: @Vincent: I don't know of a decent tutorial. However, there are examples on Stack Overflow. I suggest you search http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dom+php and try to figure it out yourself. The PHP manual reference is good, too.